# What is the book seen in 13th episode of Nichijou at 09:03?

Tags: nichijou, arawi-keiichi

I can't seem to find what cover is being printed at this timestamp.
I'm attaching both a screenshot of the frame and my attempt at showing just the book with some image manipulation in GIMP.

[image]
[image: asdf]

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you want to know? It might make the question more interesting if you have an interesting reason.